# Ошибка JNDI в java .

Tags: java, java-9

При запуске программы , вылазит ошибка :

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: java.naming.factory.initial [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.naming.factory.initial]
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:719)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:236)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:208)
    at com.company/com.company.JndiLesson.main(JndiLesson.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.naming.factory.initial
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    at java.naming/com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper.loadClass(VersionHelper.java:107)
    at java.naming/com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper.loadClass(VersionHelper.java:82)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:716)
```

Вот код программы :

```
import javax.naming.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Properties;

public class JndiLesson {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException {
        String name = "txt.txt";


        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");
        props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "file:///");

        Context initialContext = new InitialContext(props);

        //File obj = (File) initialContext.lookup(name);
        //System.out.println(obj.getName());
        // if (name.equals(""))
        //    System.out.println("Looked up the initial context");
        //else
        //    System.out.println(name + " is bound to: " + obj);

        //NamingEnumeration bindings = initialContext.listBindings("/src/");

        //  while (bindings.hasMore()) {
        //     Binding bd = (Binding) bindings.next();
        // System.out.println(bd.getName() + ": " + bd.getObject());
        //  }
    }
}
```

**Почему** возникла данная ошибка и **как** её решить?

P.S. Использую java 9

Comment: Очевидно, отсутствует класс `com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory`. Скорее всего не хватает пакета что-то вроде `fscontext.jar`. Что вы хотите реализовать?

Comment: Этот код был взят из видео-урока по RMI.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c0zW8L8IkUA&index=231&list=PL786bPIlqEjRDXpAKYbzpdTaOYsWyjtCX

Comment: @True-hacker автор видео вроде как работает с JDK 8 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uXMTq81jG7Y). Если версия JDK некритична, то лучше использовать ту же, что и автор. В девятой версии произошел ряд изменений.

Comment: @defaultlocale Спасибо за совет,попробую!

Comment: Нужно в classpath добавить `fscontext.jar`. Скачать её можно тут: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/messaging/mq/fscontext/4.5-b29/